# Using Custom Object wrapper for Request Body

Tags: spring

I have a Spring service with the following API:

```
/v1/createUser
```

Request Body

```
{
"UserId" : "some-guid-value",
"Username" : "username",
"password" : "hashed-password"
}
```

The `UserId` in the body is optional. The other values are mandatory. I would like my API controller to be defined like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "v1/createUser")
    @ResponseBody
    public void createUser(
                            @RequestBody CreatUserRequest body)
```

Now, my question is, how do I (or is it even possible to) create the CreateUserRequest class such that Spring will reject the request if it doesn't see `Username` and `password` as part of the body. `UserId` is optional and may or may not be present.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class CreatUserRequest {
  @NotBlank
  private String username, password;

  private UUID userId;
  // getter and setter
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It still goes into the controller and executes the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would complete Peter's Answer.
1. Decalre your condition using :`@NotBlank` in your DTO.
2. Validate entry on you rest controller through `@Valid`like this:

```
public void createUser(@RequestBody @Valid CreatUserRequest body)
```

This should work.